# Show that $\exists \xi\in(0,1)$ satisfying certain condition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Suppose $f\in C^3[-1,1]$ with $f(-1)=0,f(1)=1$ and $f'(0)=0$. Show that for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$, there eixsts $\xi=\xi(a)\in(0,1)$ only depending on $a$ such that
$$f'(\xi)-1=a(f(\xi)-\xi).$$

It seems that this is an application of mean value theorem or Taylor's theorem. I am also confused about the assumption $f\in C^3[-1,1]$, I didn't see how we are supposed to use this assumption. Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: Start with $g(x) = f(x)-x$; then your conditions become $g(-1) = 1$, $g(1) = 0$, and $g'(0)=0$ and the result you're shooting for is that there's a $\xi$ such that $g'(\xi)=ag(\xi)$.  Now, consider $h(x)=\ln g(x)$; what are the conditions on $h$?